# Subdomains with Apache 2.2

Tags: dns, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a Apache 2.2 to work with subdomains. I've got a domain example.de which correctly points to the IP, my site www.example.com works. Now I want a bugtracker under bugzilla.example.com. All I did was to add a vHost with Servername bugzilla.example.com, but that does not work - the error message is "Firefox can't find the server at bugzilla.example.com.". Why is that? example.com should point to the correct IP?

Comment: Sounds like your DNS isn't set up - do you get the same results if you ping www.example.com and then ping bugzilla.example.com? If not, you need to set up either a wildcard entry for *.example.com or some specific records for bugzilla.example.com

Comment: bugzilla.example.com gives a "unknown host" error, www.example.com works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did only add the vhost the most probable problem is that you didnt add the Subdomain to your DNS - Zonefile.

Comment: Ok, i didn't add it to the zonefile, so that could be the error. The problem is: I have never used zonefiles before, and I can't find any good tutorials or documentation on them. All I find are barely more than code listings.